# select sum of values: grouped by sign

Tags: sql

I have a simple SQL table of the following format:

```
date | value
============
2010-01-01 | -54
2010-01-02 | 134
2010-01-03 | 73
```

With the following two SQL queries I can select the sum of values and distinguish between the sum of positive values and the sum of negative values.

```
SELECT YEAR(date), SUM(value) FROM table WHERE value > 0 GROUP BY YEAR(date)

SELECT YEAR(date), SUM(value) FROM table WHERE value < 0 GROUP BY YEAR(date)
```

Is there a way to do this in a single SQL query?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not tested (don't know if the case can be put within a SUM instruction), but the CASE instruction could be of help:

```
SELECT 
  YEAR(date), 
  SUM(CASE WHEN value > 0 THEN value ELSE 0 END) as positives_sum,
  SUM(CASE WHEN value < 0 THEN value ELSE 0 END) as negatives_sum
FROM 
  table 
GROUP BY
  YEAR(date)
```

Comment: Yep, sorry, as I said, I did not test. Thanks for the correction :)

Comment: You could use `GREATEST(value, 0)` and `LEAST(value, 0)` instead of the conditional. Basically the same, but a little bit cleaner imo.

Answer (score 3):

Many databases have a SIGN() function

```
SELECT YEAR(date), 
       SUM(value) 
  FROM table 
 GROUP BY YEAR(date),
          SIGN(value)
```

Comment: That works but gives me a seperate row for positive and negative values. Still helpful, I didn't know SIGN(..) existed. Thanks. :)

Comment: Yes, and it would produce a 3rd row for the 0's (summed to 0 of course)